# ドットインストール Rails：TaskContlloerが生成できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_rails_v2/24923

ドットインストールでのTaskAppを学習していたところ、 
プロジェクト内で、Taskを追加していく処理ができなくてつまずいています。

```ruby
class TasksController < ApplicationController 
  def create 
    @projerct = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params) 
    redirect_to project_path(@project.id) 
  end 

  private 

  def task_pramas 
    params[:task].permit(:titele) 
  end 
end
```

[image: エラー画面]

上記のような処理をし、このようなエラメッセージが出ます。 
なんども見直し、写経しましたが、原因がわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@projerct =`の部分がtypoしています。
スペルを修正してください。

### 参考

Rubyは以下のような言語仕様があります。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.0.0/doc/spec=2fvariables.html

> `@'で始まる変数はインスタンス変数であり、特定の オブジェクトに所属しています。インスタンス変数はそのクラスま たはサブクラスのメソッドから参照できます。 **初期化されていない インスタンス変数を参照した時の値はnilです。**

typoしていた`@projerct`は初期化されていますが、正しいスペルの`@project`は初期化されていなかったので`nil`となり、`nil`に対して`tasks`メソッドを呼びだしたので、質問のようなエラーが発生しています。

今後も「うっかり」やってしまう可能性があるので、注意してくださいね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
単純なみすから、その原因まで細かくご指導いただき感謝します。